# Limit my upload speed at OS level ?

Tags: macos, data-transfer

I know my upload speed is limited at about 100/110KB/s, sometimes I reach this limit and it impacts the connexion of other computer of my home network.

Is there a way to tell OSX to limit its upload speed to (for example) 80KB/s ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Network Link Conditioner

You can create a custom profile for Network Link Conditioner, using the following settings:

[image]
[image]

<sup>It is a free download in Xcode (go to Xcode → Open Developer Tool → More Developer Tools… and download the **Hardware IO Tools for Xcode**).</sup>

Comment: That's exactly the kind of tool I was looking for !

Comment: Solved my issue as well. Was using all upload bandwidth and ended up killing the internet completely when I was uploading files for work. Now I can upload and use the internet at the same time! Imagine that!

Comment: allow me to push my LFS objects to work git, without disconnecting my kids' zoom school session!

Answer (score 11):

Two ways that I can think of:

**1.** Install Apple's [Network Link Conditioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659382/installing-apples-network-link-conditioner-tool)

**2.** Use `ipfw` commands to create a pipe and limit bandwidth:

`sudo ipfw pipe 1 config bw 80KByte/s`

`sudo ipfw add 1 pipe 1 src-port 80`

To disable the pipe:

`sudo ipfw delete 1`